# Understanding shape of laplacian-embedded signal

Tags: signal-processing, manifold-learning

I have a periodic signal for which I:

a) extract main signal mode

b) split that signal mode into windows of size 20 and create vectors of size 20 and

c) do Laplacian embedding for this collection of 20th-dimension vectors:
[image]

Why do the eigenvectors have this nice saddle shape?